# JSONP call works local but not on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm currently trying to get data from a remote server using jQuery and perform an jsonp ajax call. The problem is that whenever I use a local server the response gets evaluated, when I use a remote server it's not. The response is in the form jsonp12345678[{"key":"value"}] hence, using [ instead of ( as usually with JSON. Unfortunately I don't have access to the remote server to change that.

Here's my javascript call.

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
            url: 'url',
            error: function(status) {
                console.log(status);
            },
            success: function (html) {
                $("#content").text(html.reply);
            },
        });
```

Comment: That sure doesn't look like valid JSONP to me.

Comment: The error callback will unfortunately not work with jsonp.

Comment: The call works on a local machine and the response string is identical on local and remote machine. However, using [ around the key-value pairs doesn't work remotely. Only ( around key-value-pairs works locall and remotely. Any reason why?

Comment: Apparently having the call from remote to remote also doesn't like the [ brackets. So it's probably right, that jQuery ajax only likes ( brackets.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote server doesn't support jsonp, you will not be able to do jsonp queries to it. The server has to explicitly call the jsonp callback.

Answer (score 0):

JSON-P needs to actually be making a function call with the data. The only thing I can think of is to put a proxy script between the remote and local that reformats it. But if you are going to do that then you can just use AJAX.

Comment: What do you mean with function call. I thought $.ajax generates the temporary function automatically and uses "jsonpxxxxxx" as name. This name is then prepended to the [{array}].

Comment: Most implementations that I have seen pass a callback parameter which jQuery can generate for you and the response is a function call to that callback function with the data as a parameter. 'jsonp12345678[{"key":"value"}]' this does not make any sense... why would it respond back with the whole object as an array index thats part of a callback auto-generated array.

I'd make a simple proxy script that either strips the Broken JSON-P off of the response so that it returns normal JSON and use AJAX, or just replace the brackets with parentheses and use local JSON-P.